# Send array by jQuery to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I have the following `div` tags that are created dynamically:

```
<div class="inContainer clonado" data-clone="Si" data-idgaleria="3" data-color="c79471 id=" clone2 ">
<div class="inContainer clonado " data-clone="Si " data-idgaleria="4 " data-color="c6578 " id="clone3 ">
```

Through drag and drop the element moves in the body. Then in the database I try to save the id of the element and its left and top position.

To capture these properties I am forming an arrangement as follows.

```
$(".clonado").each(function() {
   var posicion = $(this).position();
   divClonados[$(this).attr('id')] =  [$(this).attr('data-idgaleria'),posicion.left,posicion.top];
});
```

I already explained this, the problem is when I want to send this arrangement to PHP. I am doing it in the following way:

```
$.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: "POST",
      data:divClonados,                          
      success: function(data) {
         console.log(data);
      }
});
```

Is this form bad? And how should you receive them in PHP?

Comment: Looks fine to me, what have you done on the PHP side of things?

Comment: Could you tell me what you have in your php?
I have tried with several codes last I have this: 
$myArray =   $_REQUEST['divClonados'];
print_r($myArray) ;

Comment: If you'd like to access the variable like that you'll have to change the JS code to `data: {divClonados:divClonados},`.

Comment: I already tried it I get Undefined index: divClonados, I appreciate that you want to help me!

Comment: Just realised `$_POST["divClonados"]` is probably better suited.

Comment: The same error appears(Undefined index: divClonados) with $myArray = $_POST["divClonados"];
        print_r($myArray);

Comment: hmmm, try `$_POST["data"]` and if that doesn't work I'd try sending it as JSON and parsing at the PHP end.

Comment: Sorry for my absence, I was busy on another project.
Can you tell me how it would be by json?

Comment: Shouldn't make a difference thinking about it, try printing out `divClonados` in your JS, before you send the request to make sure it's not `undefined`.